# How to set Device orientation for flutter web?

Tags: flutter, orientation, device

We can set device orientation for flutter apps by using SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([.....]) . But this doesn't work in case of flutter web. so how to set the device orientation in flutter web apps.

Answer (score 0):

After reseach I found that the most effective way to handle the issue is to use
`RotatedBox` https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RotatedBox-class.html

You should use it with `MediaQuery.of(context).orientation` to check whether the rotation is needed.
Use `RotatedBox` on highest level in build method:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RotatedBox(...);
}
```

Comment: Works, but the Rotated Box makes a blur on my Widgets... Any solution?